# SQLDeveloper, Oracle Procedures with Error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any way to know why the procedures are in error? 
They compile well.

[image]

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please supply the error you are receiving in your question instead of a link to an image? It would help the community get you an answer quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in SQL Developer under "Errors" tab:

[image]

<sup>Image source: https://thatjeffsmith.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/show_errors3.png</sup>

Related: [Viewing PLSQL Compilation Errors in Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/viewing-plsql-compilation-errors-in-oracle-sql-developer/)

Comment: Are they in an error state? Or an invalid state due to dependencies on other objects? Have you recompiled the schema?

Comment: your plsql can be invalid without havign an errors, per Michale's comment